# spyOn with Promise

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have the following function that I would like to spy... but it contains a promise... But I am getting TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'modalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).then')

Because of course I have just spyOn(modalService,'showModal')

How do I account for the promise too so ??

```
_modalService = {
    close: function (value) { console.log(value) },
    dismiss: function (value) { console.log(value) },
    showModal: function (value) { console.log(value) }
};

spyOn(_modalService, 'close');
spyOn(_modalService, 'dismiss');
spyOn(_modalService, 'showModal');
```

Controller function:

```
user.resetPassword = function () {
            var modalOptions = {
                closeButtonText: 'Cancel',
                actionButtonText: 'Reset',
                headerText: 'Reset Password',
                bodyText: 'Are you sure you want to reset the users password?'
            };

            modalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).then(function (result) {
                if (result === 'ok') {
                    userDataService.resetPassword(user.data).then(function (result) {
                        $scope.$emit('showSuccessReset');
                    });

                };
            });
        };
```

Here is my unit test:

```
it('should allow the users password to be reset', function () {
        var controller = createController();
        controller.resetPassword();
        $httpBackend.flush();
    })
```

*******************UPDATE

So I change it to this:

```
 //Create a fake instance of the modal instance. TO ensure that the close is called
        _modalService = {
            close: function (value) { console.log(value) },
            dismiss: function (value) { console.log(value) },
            showModal: function (value) { console.log(value) }
        };

        spyOn(_modalService, 'close');
        spyOn(_modalService, 'dismiss');
        spyOn(_modalService, 'showModal').and.callThrough();

        _modalService.showModal = function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.resolve('Remote call result');
                return deferred.promise;   
            };
```

To be honest though I am not sure I could explain this. While I understand all the async stuff... I am not sure how jasmine is using this to make it all work. Can anyone explain the flow???? Also I feel the syntax is wrong... how would you typically write this so it looks better/cleaner...??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you need to mock a function that returns a promise, you have two options:

1. Return a mocked promise (an object that resembles a promise);
2. Return a real promise.

I suggest #2 because it's easier and you don't have to worry about replicating the whole promise API. In other words, it isn't worth mocking a promise itself.

Now about Jasmine: you only need to use `spyOn` when you already have an object (not a mock) and you want to spy on (no pun intended) one of its methods. In your case, your whole object is fake, so you could use `jasmine.createSpyObj` instead.

The following example should make all of the above clearer:

**SUT**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, modal, service) {
  $scope.click = function() {
    modal.show().then(function(result) {
      if (result === 'ok') {
        service.resetPassword();
      }
    });
  };
});
```

**Test**

```
describe('Testing a controller', function() {
  var $scope, $q,
      ctrl, modalMock, serviceMock;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('plunker');

    modalMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('modal', ['show']);
    serviceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('service', ['resetPassword']);

    inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _$q_) {
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      $q = _$q_;

      ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: $scope,
        modal: modalMock,
        service: serviceMock
      });
    });
  });

  it('should reset the password when the user confirms', function() {
    // Arrange
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    deferred.resolve('ok');
    modalMock.show.and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

    // Act
    $scope.click();
    $scope.$digest(); // Makes Angular resolve the promise

    // Assert
    expect(serviceMock.resetPassword).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should not reset the password when the user cancels', function() {
    // Arrange
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    deferred.resolve('cancel');
    modalMock.show.and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

    // Act
    $scope.click();
    $scope.$digest(); // Makes Angular resolve the promise

    // Assert
    expect(serviceMock.resetPassword).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QjyY1Hl02CqzMMa4Ospk?p=preview)

That mock arrangement code within each test could be moved into a `beforeEach` section so it doesn't get duplicated. I didn't do that in order to make things simple.